# Google map label with marker like the search result

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

If I search for a place in Google Maps, I get the marker with the name of the location in red text beside it.

[image]

Is there a way to replicate this with my website with Google Maps API?

I have tried to add my marker using the method on Google's developer site (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers) but rather than searching by location, it requires the exact coordinates, and there doesn't seem to be a way of adding the red text beside it.

There is the `title` property of the Marker, but that results in just a tooltip.

My code so far...

```
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var vmotion = {lat: 52.671648, lng: -8.552518};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 15,
      center: vmotion
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: vmotion,
      map: map,
      title: 'VMotion IT Solutions Ltd.'
    });
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map Label library here:  https://github.com/googlemaps/js-map-label.

Example here; https://googlemaps.github.io/js-map-label/examples/maplabel.html

You use it like this:

```
  var mapLabel = new MapLabel({
          text: 'Test',
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(34.03, -118.235),
          map: map,
          fontSize: 35,
          align: 'right'
        });
        mapLabel.set('position', new google.maps.LatLng(34.03, -118.235));
```